# Show posts count for Categories and Tags in wp_nav_menu

Tags: posts, menus, woocommerce-offtopic, navigation, count

I'm trying to show WooCommerce Product Categories, Post Categories, Product Tags, Post Tags and Custom Taxonomy posts count in main navigation using wp_nav_menu.

My WP_NAV_MENU code

```
                <?php if( has_nav_menu( 'primary_menu' ) ) : ?>
                    <?php
                        $primary_args = array(
                            'theme_location'    => 'primary_menu',
                            'echo' => false,
                            'depth'             => 3,
                            'container'         => false,
                            'menu_class'        => 'header-menu',
                            'menu_id'           => 'header-menu'
                        );
                        wp_nav_menu( $primary_args );
                    ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I added the following code into my child-theme functions.php

```
apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'menu_post_count', 10, 4 );
function menu_post_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args )
{
    // Check $item and get the data you need
    printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( $item, true ) );
    // Then append whatever you need to the $output
    $output .= '';

    return $output;
}
```

This caused error on site showing the data of the category as following.

```
WP_Post::__set_state(array(
   'ID' => 153,
   'post_author' => '1',
   'post_date' => '2015-12-22 21:52:07',
   'post_date_gmt' => '2015-12-22 19:52:07',
   'post_content' => ' ',
   'post_title' => '',
   'post_excerpt' => '',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'comment_status' => 'closed',
   'ping_status' => 'closed',
   'post_password' => '',
   'post_name' => '153',
   'to_ping' => '',
   'pinged' => '',
   'post_modified' => '2015-12-29 08:47:30',
   'post_modified_gmt' => '2015-12-29 06:47:30',
   'post_content_filtered' => '',
   'post_parent' => 0,
   'guid' => 'http://domain.com/?p=153',
   'menu_order' => 1,
   'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
   'post_mime_type' => '',
   'comment_count' => '0',
   'filter' => 'raw',
   'db_id' => 153,
   'menu_item_parent' => '0',
   'object_id' => '39',
   'object' => 'page',
   'type' => 'post_type',
   'type_label' => 'page',
   'url' => 'http://domain.com/',
   'title' => 'homepage',
   'target' => '',
   'attr_title' => '',
   'description' => '',
   'classes' =>
```

Comment: That doesnt look like an error to me. It's doing exactly what you told it to. var_export will the data assigned to that variable.

Comment: @Nath I found this code some place here please advise the best code edited to end with the requested result? And if you have other suggestion , thank you!

Comment: Do you have the post categories / tags / taxonomies added to you menu already??

Comment: @Nath Yes I do have them using the Appearance > Menu

Answer (score 3):

Alright so this isn't too difficult, first we will just check if the menu item is a taxonomy then get the count and display it!

```
function ggstyle_menu_item_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    // Check if the item is a Category or Custom Taxonomy
    if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' ) {
        $object = get_term($item->object_id, $item->object);

        // Check count, if more than 0 display count
        if($object->count > 0)
            $output .= "<span class='menu-item-count'>".$object->count."</span>";
    }    

    return $output;
}
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'ggstyle_menu_item_count', 10, 4 );
```

### Edit

To get the Item count to output into the `<a>` of the menu item we will have to split up the $output and insert our content the put it back together.

```
function ggstyle_menu_item_count( $output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    // Check if the item is a Category or Custom Taxonomy
    if( $item->type == 'taxonomy' ) {
        $object = get_term($item->object_id, $item->object);

        // Check count, if more than 0 display count
        if($object->count > 0) {
            $output_new = '';
            $output_split = str_split($output, strpos($output, '</a>') );
            $output_new .= $output_split[0] . "<span class='menu-item-count'>".$object->count."</span>" . $output_split[1];
            $output = $output_new;
        }
    }    

    return $output;
}
add_action( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'ggstyle_menu_item_count', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: @Naith thank you for your reply. Should I only add this into the child functions.php anything required to be done at wp_nav_menu level?

Comment: Yeah just in your functions. The action it hooks into 'walker_nav_menu_start_el' is part of the wp_nav_menu function.

Comment: I've applied the code thanks a lot it's working fine however it has messed up with the style thus is it possible to embed the count into the <a> tag rather then an individual span to be linkable and fits with the site style. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ngearing
Thank you for the proposed solution, I would like to improve it a little :

- add brackets ( and ) before and after the count number
- be able to apply this code only to one of the menus (name Categories) of the site

Would you be so kind as to propose an edit for these two ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/255699)